# UIswitch duplicate issue in table cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my App, I have a tableview with 7 sections and each section has 8cells containing Stepper(in UIView),UIButton(in UIView) and UISwitch(in UIview).
Now I am able to set and get values for stepper and UIButton But my issue is with UISwitch.
It is getting reused and shows On/Off states simultaneously(wiered UI).
Also I have maintained an Array to save status of switch but it doesnot reflect properly.
Below is the code

```
var myData1 : [Bool] = [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]

 let cell:DefaultTableViewCell = (self.tblviewSwitchPOints.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "defaultcell", for: indexPath) as? DefaultTableViewCell)!

    cell.viewForButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.viewForSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
    print("in cell for row")

    if indexPath.section == 0
    {
        switch indexPath.row
        {
        case 0:
            cell.lblMain.text = timePerDay[indexPath.row]
            cell.lblTemp.text = row1[0]
            cell.lblTime.text = row1[1]
            cell.lblMain.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.viewForStepper.addSubview(valueStepper1)
            cell.viewForButton.addSubview(btnCustom1)
            cell.viewForSwitch.addSubview(switchOnOff1)

            if myData1.count==0
            {

            }else
            {
                switchOnOff1.isOn = myData1[0]
            }
            switchOnOff1.tag = 0
            switchOnOff1.addTarget(self,action:#selector(actionOnOff1(sender:)), for:.valueChanged )

            let temp = arrTemp1[indexPath.row]
            if arrTimeInDouble1.count==0
            {

            }else if temp.elementsEqual("FFFF")
            {
                valueStepper1.value = 5
            }else
            {
                 valueStepper1.value = arrTimeInDouble1[indexPath.row]
            }

            valueStepper1.tag = indexPath.row

            btnCustom1.tag = indexPath.row
            if arrTime1.count==0
            {

            }else
            {
                btnCustom1.titleLabel?.text = arrTime1[indexPath.row]
            }

            valueStepper1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChangedTemp1(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
            btnCustom1.addTarget(self, action:#selector(datePickerTapped1), for: .touchUpInside)
            print("in cell fro row1\(myData1)\(switchOnOff3.isOn)\(switchOnOff1.tag)")
            return cell


         case 1:
            cell.lblMain.text =  timePerDay[indexPath.row]
            cell.lblTemp.text = row2[0]
            cell.lblTime.text = row2[1]
            cell.lblMain.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.viewForStepper.addSubview(valueStepper2)
            cell.viewForSwitch.addSubview(switchOnOff2)
            if myData1.count==0
            {

            }else
            {
                switchOnOff2.isOn = myData1[1]
            }
            switchOnOff2.tag = indexPath.row
            if arrTimeInDouble1.count==0
            {

            }else
            {
                valueStepper2.value = arrTimeInDouble1[indexPath.row]
            }

            cell.viewForButton.addSubview(btnCustom2)
            btnCustom2.tag=indexPath.row
            valueStepper2.tag = indexPath.row

            if arrTime1.count==0
            {

            }else
            {
                btnCustom2.titleLabel?.text = arrTime1[indexPath.row]
            }

            switchOnOff2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionOnOff1(sender:)), for:.valueChanged )
            valueStepper2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChangedTemp1(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
            btnCustom2.addTarget(self, action:#selector(datePickerTapped1), for: .touchUpInside)

            return cell
     }
```

Comment: Add code for other indexPath case.

Comment: @ivarun Please check the code I've edited.

Comment: switchOnOff2 must used in both if-else block

Comment: @ManishMahajan You are right but by doing the same it did not really help.

Answer (score 0):

A lot may have gone wrong but what I suspect in your case is that each of your switches has multiple target/action pairs assigned; You dequeue a cell and then call `addTarget` on switches where a previous target is still on the switch.

In any case what is best done when dealing in these situations is to put most of your code into your table view cell. I actually suggest you to use delegate to get messages back from cell to your view controller so dequeuing should look something like this:

```
let cell: DefaultTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "defaultcell", for: indexPath) as! DefaultTableViewCell
cell.myObject = myObjectSections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
cell.delegate = self
return cell
```

Nothing else. Now cell should do all the logic:

```
class DefaultTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate: DefaultTableViewCellDelegate?
    var myObject: MyObject? {
        didSet { refresh() }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.switch.addTarget(self, action:#selector(switchMoved)), for:.valueChanged)
    }
    func refresh() {
        // Change all UI related stuff here
    }

    @objc private func switchMoved() {
        if let myObject = myObject {
            delegate?.defaultTableViewCell(self, didChangeWhateverStateOf:myObject to: switch.on)
        }
    }

}
```

Naturally a protocol needs to be defined appropriately. For my case that is

```
protocol DefaultTableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func defaultTableViewCell(_ sender: DefaultTableViewCell, didChangeWhateverStateOf myObject: MyObject, to flag: Bool)
}
```

and your view controller needs to implement this protocol.

Sometimes it may actually make sense to add an index path with the data as well. To do so you simply upgrade this code so cell also contains `var indexPath: IndexPath!`. Now after dequeuing a cell you assign its new index path. And then in your delegate method you can access it at any time:

```
extension MyViewController: DefaultTableViewCellDelegate {
    func defaultTableViewCell(_ sender: DefaultTableViewCell, didChangeWhateverStateOf myObject: MyObject, to flag: Bool) {
        print("This is cell at section \(sender.indexPath.section), row: \(sender.indexPath.row)")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be good if you create a custom cell with UISwitch in it. Then you can assign value to the switch like this -

```
    var cell : SwitchTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifier") as? SwitchTableViewCell
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = SwitchTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "CellIdentifier")
    }
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        if(myData1.count != 0)
        {
            cell?.switchOnOff.isOn = myData1[indexPath.row];
        }
    }
    return cell!;
```